# Group users by at least one of two parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, graph-databases

I need to group users so that they are grouped together if they have the same name or email. That is, to combine them into one group it is not necessary that everyone has the same e-mail or name, it is enough that the name or e-mail coincides with at least one other user. The desired result in the picture.

I've tried using Dense_Rank for name and email, but I don't know if I can combine them.

```
create table #a (UserID int, Name varchar(25), Email Varchar(50))

insert into #a
values 
(1, 'Marvin Cottrell', '123456@gmail.com'),
(2, 'Colleen Morrison', 'somebody@gmail.com'),
(3, 'Colleen Morrison', 'cm@gmail.com'),
(4, 'Dante Henry', '765@gmail.com'),
(5, 'Willie Alcock', '123456@gmail.com'),
(6, 'Marvin Cottrell', 'lib@gmail.com'),
(7, 'Cecilia Mueller', '765@gmail.com'),
(8, 'Cathal Compton', '765@gmail.com'),
(9, 'Giovanni Tapia', '123456@gmail.com'),
(10, 'Humphrey Macias', 'somebody@gmail.com')

select *,   DENSE_RANK () over (order by Name desc) as DENSE
from #a

select *,   DENSE_RANK () over (order by Email desc) as DENSE
from #a
```

[image: example]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Hint: Rank or Dense_Rank

Comment: The problem seems to be more complex than initially thought. Seems like the solution amounts to divide the graph into non-connected subgraphs, where each subgraph corresponds to a group.

Comment: @DaleK I tried Dense_Rank but how can it help?? if I had ideas, I wouldn't ask, I don't even know how to formulate a query to find information

Comment: If you tried dense_rank then show us...

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). The Impaler and I had more work than necessary in order to generate test data (as you can see from our fiddles). Please show your data as text next time, so we can copy and paste. Better even show create table and insert statements or even build a fiddle with sample data. Make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: What happens if you have three users, 1 and 2 have the same name, and 2 and 3 have the same email?

Comment: @Charlieface 1 and 2 and 3 should be added to one group

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with a recursive query. For every user ID I go from related row to related row and remember all IDs I already looked up in the chain (ids) and the maximum user ID (maxid, which will finally become my group key).

```
with cte (userid, otherid, name, email, maxid, ids) as
(
  select
    userid, userid, name, email, userid, '#' + cast(userid as varchar(max)) + '#'
  from mytable
  union all
  select
    cte.userid, t.userid, t.name, t.email, 
    case when t.userid > cte.userid then t.userid else cte.userid end,
    cte.ids + cast(t.userid as varchar(max)) + '#'
  from cte
  join mytable t on cte.ids not like '%#' + cast(t.userid as varchar) + '#%'
                 and (t.name = cte.name or t.email = cte.email)
)
select userid, dense_rank() over (order by max(maxid)) as grp
from cte 
group by userid 
order by max(maxid), userid;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=826abe47fbc996696472731937f9a733

Comment: Clever use of ID separated by #. It's possible to do it in SQL Server after all.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner thank you! Would it be optimal to use this to process a large amount of data 100-500K rows every hour?

Comment: This is a laborious task. Try it and see how fast it is. But no matter how fast, It is definitely not optimal, because you are evaluating the same information again and again. A more efficient way would be a data warehouse approach where you store this information redundantly (which is something we usually try to avoid in a relational database). This means store the group ID in the database and every time a user gets added, deleted or updated only determine the affected group(s).

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner Unfortunately, even for 16 thousand lines, recursion takes a very long time, and I need to process several million. Is there some other method? do you know where to read about it? I don’t even understand how to formulate a query in Google correctly to find the information I need

Comment: No idea, sorry. This is a complex thing and recursion is the typical approach here. However, SQL is set based. A programming language may be better, as you can write it such that it doesn't look at the same rows again and again. PostgreSQL's recursive query as shown by The Impaler may already be better than what SQL Server offers here, but a programing language would even be better I guess. PostgreSQL and Oracle have programming languages built into the DBMS, but SQL Server doesn't.

Comment: The other approach I mentioned above that only deals with the delta on inserts, updates and deletes should be best in terms of performance anyway. Only, for this you still have to find the initial groups, and you are back to the recursive query :-( Maybe write a query that only finds the user chain for a single user. Then run it again to find the chain for the next user not yet in a group, and so on. Thus you have a recursive query that is not so heavyweight, but you'll have to run it again and again until all users are in a group.

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer you probably want to hear, but I don't think this query can be written in SQL Server. It requires the engine to implement `UNION` in recursive CTEs, but SQL Server doesn't [yet] implement it.

This can be done in PostgreSQL, however, as shown below:

```
with recursive
n as (
  select name as r, id, name, email from t
 union -- this is what's missing in SQL Server
  select n.r, t.*
  from n
  join t on t.name = n.name or t.email = n.email
),
m as(
  select r, min(id) as mid
  from n
  group by r
),
l as (
  select *, row_number() over() as g
  from (select *, row_number() over(partition by mid order by r) as rn from m) x
  where rn = 1
)
select n.id, n.name, n.email, l.g
from n
join l on l.r = n.r
order by n.id;
```

Result:

```
 id  name  email               g 
 --- ----- ------------------- - 
 1   mc    12345@gmail.com     1 
 2   cm    somebody@gmail.com  2 
 3   cm    cm@gmail.com        2 
 4   dh    765@gmail.com       3 
 5   wa    12345@gmail.com     1 
 6   mc    lib@gmail.com       1 
 7   cmu   765@gmail.com       3 
 8   cc    765@gmail.com       3 
 9   gt    12345@gmail.com     1 
 10  hm    somebody@gmail.com  2
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1aac0f2a82eb32e92468fc74b099b666).

Comment: Yep, PostgreSQL is much better than SQL Server when it comes to recursive queries. Still, I didn't know, you can use `UNION` to dismiss rows from the recursive part. Thank you for sharing this.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner This is basically because the design of SQL Server's recursive CTE setup is that it effectively functions similar to Oracle's `CONNECT BY`, and therefore only looks at one row at a time. This is why set operators cannot be used, and why window functions return strange results